# Gradle build failed at :compileJava: `No matching variant`

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, bukkit, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying making a library for Minecraft Bukkit (Paper) plugin. I'm trying to build a jar file, but Gradle gives me this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
```

I'd never seen this error before.

```
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT:20220703.182221-166 was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 16, preferably in the form of class files, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT declares an API of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 16
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 16)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 16
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 16)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
```

The full output log is so long that I have uploaded it to pastebin:

[With -scan -debug (full output)](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/2mrjNTrthf/)

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("maven-publish")
}

group = "ml.windleaf"
version = "1.0.1"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://jitpack.io")
    maven("https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/")
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1")
    implementation("io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.18.0")
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

allprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java")
    apply(plugin = "java-library")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven("https://jitpack.io")
        maven("https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/")
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0")
        implementation("org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:3.8.5")
    }

    tasks {
        compileJava {
            options.encoding = "UTF-8"
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create("maven_public", MavenPublication::class) {
            groupId = "ml.windleaf"
            artifactId = "PlugApi"
            version = version
            from(components.getByName("java"))
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone please help me to analyse why it gives such an error.

Comment: I guess it might be the Java version and the library mismatch, but I've been using it this way before and it didn't give an error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tl;dr: The [Paper API docs](https://papermc.io/using-the-api#gradle) say to set the Java version to 17 - it doesn't look like you've done that. Try adding

```kotlin
java {
    toolchain.languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
}
```

#### Explanation

The error that Gradle gives you is verbose, but it does explain what's going on.  Let's break it down

The first bit that's interesting is this:

```
Could not resolve io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Gradle can't find the dependency that you've declared. From looking at the [Paper API docs](https://papermc.io/using-the-api#gradle) you're using the right Maven Repository, and the right dependency, so Gradle must have another reason...

```
No matching variant of 
io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT:20220703.182221-166 
was found.

The consumer was configured to find an API of a library compatible with Java 16
```

Basically, the "the consumer" (that's your project) is saying "I need something that works with Java 16, because that's what I'm using".

```
Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17
and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 16
```

Now Gradle has found something really close, but it's disqualified because it's using Java 17 - which doesn't match what your project needs.

Gradle also lists some other variants, but they're also disqualified because they're not a Java library - they're source code, or Javadoc variants.